# Duplicating values in a column for all rows in a given id

Tags: mysql

I have a table of Ids with "orders" and "shipment" timestamps.  Most Ids will have both "orders" and "shipment" rows, but some Ids will only have shipment. I want to implement a If-Then Logic where if I see an order row, then retrieve the timestamp.  If an Id does not contain an Order row, then I will resort to retrieving the "shipment" timestamp.

One way I was trying to solve this was creating a case statement to create a new 'Orders' column and populate that specific timestamp for each Orders and Shipment Row.  I'll create a subquery where if Orders column is not null, then use that timestamp.  Or if Orders column is null, then use the shipment timestamp.

I can't simply just filter by rows = "orders" because it'll eliminate the IDs that only contains shipments

Original Table:

```
id    Type     Date    
1     orders    3/28     
1     shipment    3/23
```

Expected Result:

```
id    Type       Date    Orders_Column
1     orders      3/28    3/28
1     shipment     3/23   3/28
```

Comment: How are those two rows linked to each other? They don't have the same `id` value...

Comment: my bad. It should be 1 for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `LEFT JOIN` of the table to itself, looking for a matching `orders` row for the `id`. If there isn't a matching row, the `shipment` date is used:

```
SELECT o1.*, COALESCE(o2.Date, o1.Date) AS `Date`
FROM orders o1
LEFT JOIN orders o2 ON o2.id = o1.id AND o2.Type = 'orders'
```

Output (for a demo with an extra shipment only id):

```
id  Type        Date    Date
1   orders      3/28    3/28
1   shipment    3/23    3/28
2   shipment    3/25    3/25
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/34Bt3gBx1VANCLX5eQje6S/1)